# Insertion in database after ajax call works with firefox 58 but not with chrome 63

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, google-chrome

I'm on a wordpress based website and my problem is that under chrome (and IE and Edge), the data I send to be written in my database is never written.
But under Firefox, it works well !

I can't explain why there is a difference so I describe the path of these datas. May you could find where is the magic !

After getting data from users click, I send them through AJAX with these lines :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo get_bloginfo('url').'/insert/'; ?>",
        // data: "id_company=" + idcompany + "&id_proposition=" + idProposition + "&id_section=" + idSection + "&id_audit=" + id_audit + "&valeur=" + valeur
  data: {
      'id_company': idcompany,
      'id_proposition': idProposition,
      'id_section': idSection,
      'id_audit': id_audit,
      'valeur': valeur
  }
```

When I look into the Chrome console, the datas sent are the good ones and exactly the same as in firefox. I even verified the type, all are strings.

Then, in my "insert" file, I have these lines :

```
elseif(isset($_POST['id_audit'])){
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $reponses[$key] = $value;
 }
 register_iso_reponses($reponses);}
```

And the register function is that :

```
function register_iso_reponses($reponses){
global $wpdb;
$reponse['date'] = date("Y-m-d");
$rep_exist = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "
        SELECT *
        FROM ss1_iso_reponses
        WHERE id_entreprise = %s
        AND id_proposition= %s
        AND id_audit= %s
        ",
        $reponses['id_company'], $reponses['id_proposition'], $reponses['id_audit']
    ), ARRAY_A
);
if(!$rep_exist){
$isinsert = $wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare(
            "
            INSERT INTO ss1_iso_reponses
            ( id_proposition, id_section, id_entreprise, valeur, id_audit, dateReponse )
            VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s )
            ",
            $reponses['id_proposition'], $reponses['id_section'],
            $reponses['id_company'],    $reponses['valeur'],
            $reponses['id_audit'], $reponse['date']
        )
    );
}else{
$isupdate = $wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare(
            "
            UPDATE ss1_iso_reponses
            SET valeur = %s, dateReponse = %s
            WHERE id_entreprise = %s
            AND id_proposition = %s
            AND id_audit = %s
            ",
            $reponses['valeur'], $reponse['date'],
            $reponses['id_company'], $reponses['id_proposition'],
            $reponses['id_audit']
        )
    );
  }}
```

Do you see something that could make it malfunction under chrome ??

Comment: What's the HTTP response code in Chrome? Are you properly logging all PHP errors, and have checked the log?

Comment: you should add some logs server side to see the difference.

Comment: Thx, I just add some PHP logs (with methods 1 and 2 from https://digwp.com/2009/07/monitor-php-errors-wordpress/ ), but after correcting the few variables errors, I don't have any more error logged but still get my problem...